# How to use error propagation formula in equation with inseparable variables?

Tags: nuclear-physics, mathematics, error-analysis, statistics, data-analysis

$$
R_i(t) =
\frac{\mu_{s,E_i}+\mu_{s,E_0}}{\mu_{s,E_i}-\mu_{s,E_0}}
\cdot
\frac{e^{-\rho\sqrt2\mu_{s,E_0}}-e^{-\rho\sqrt2\mu_{s,E_i}}}{1-e^{-\rho\sqrt2(\mu_{s,E_0}+\mu_{s,E_i})}}.
$$

How do I can find error in $\rho$ using error propagation formula? I have found the error in $R_i(t)$,$\mu_{s,E_0}$ and $\mu_{s,E_i}$ using the collected data

Comment: Please check that my edit is correct. Your original equation is too complicated to make this conversion at a glance. Also, you have to tell us what you have: Do you mean to say that you have $R_i$ and all the $\mu_s$ and their errors, and now want to find out what $\rho$ and its error are? Isn't it more common to have $\rho$ and its error, propagating into $R_i$? It is not clear what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for editing my question. In my experiment I have to find the value of $\rho$ by finding the value the of $\mu_{S,E_0}$ and a function $R_i(t)$ and then I need to calculate the error in  $\rho$ using the error propagation

Comment: Welcome Anchal Kumar Sharma to Physics Stack Exchange. Please clarify if the $\mu_{S,E_0}$ and $\mu_{S,E_i}$ values also have uncertainties.

Comment: yes I have uncertainity in $\mu_{S,E_0}$ and $\mu_{S,E_i}$ also

Answer (score 1):

Error propagation formulae follow from how a small change in one variable affects another variable.  If the uncertainties are small and the variables are uncorrelated, all you need to do is differentiate the right hand side of the equation, i.e.

$$dR=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho} d\rho + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mu_{\mathrm{s}, E_0}} d\mu_{\mathrm{s}, E_0}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mu_{\mathrm{s}, E_i}} d\mu_{\mathrm{s}, E_i}$$

so the uncertainty in $\rho$ is

$$ \sigma_\rho^2 = \left[\sigma_R^2 - \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mu_{\mathrm{s}, E_0}}\right)^2 \sigma_{\mu_{\mathrm{s}, E_0}}^2 - \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mu_{\mathrm{s}, E_i}}\right)^2 \sigma_{\mu_{\mathrm{s}, E_i}}^2 \right] \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho}\right)^{-2}$$

where

$$f\equiv \frac{{\left[\left\{\exp \left(-\rho \sqrt{2} \mu_{\mathrm{s}, E_0}\right)-\exp \left(-\rho\sqrt{2} \mu_{\mathrm{s}, E_i}\right)\right\}\right.} \left.\left\{\mu_{\mathrm{s}, E_i}+\mu_{\mathrm{s}, E_0}\right\}\right]}{\left[\left\{1-\exp \left(-\rho \sqrt{2}\left(\mu_{\mathrm{s}, E_0}\right.\right.\right.\right.  \left.\left.\left.\left.+\mu_{\mathrm{s}, E_i}\right)\right)\right\}\left\{\mu_{\mathrm{s}, E_i}-\mu_{\mathrm{s}, E_0}\right\}\right]} $$

If the uncertainties are large or there are singularities, however, you should run a computational Monte Carlo simulation. Randomly generate sets of possible $R$, $\mu_{\mathrm{s}, E_0}$, and $\mu_{\mathrm{s}, E_i}$ values according to their uncertainties, and numerically solve for $\rho$ for each set. You then get your error on $\rho$ from the distribution of $\rho$ values, taking the standard deviation or 68% interval or however you are defining your error.